# rich:dataScroller is too narrow for big numbers

Tags: jsf, richfaces

There seems to be an issue with page numbers while displaying huge data. I see that page numbers are "duplicated". I am attaching the screenshot and the code snippet of `rich:dataScroller`. Please do let me know how to overcome this or if there is any extra property to be set to display the page numbers correctly.

This happens for data with more than say 100000 records with both server and client side pagination.

```
<rich:dataScroller for="categoryTable" maxPages="5" fastStep="100">
</rich:dataScroller>
```

[image]

Comment: Data scroller code.<rich:dataScroller for="categoryTable" maxPages="5" fastStep="100">
               </rich:dataScroller>

Comment: Are those really duplicates or do you just not see the whole label?

Comment: @krishnanbalakrishnan Look at my answer and tell me if you need another solution ;-)

Comment: Emil Sierżęga - thanks... i will try this option and update post, just needed a clarification, in your case I see that there is no issue with the page numbers as such, but it is about the space where the page number is placed.

Answer (score 0):

By default RF uses here (pretty weak) CSS rule like this:

```
.rf-ds-nmb-btn {
    width: 2em;
}
```

This is one of the first things I overwrite. Just add your own code:

```
.rf-ds-nmb-btn {
    width: auto;
}
```

For number likes 19996-20000 it changes from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]